# Pass task results from preceding tasks celery

Tags: python, celery

Here is my code. I want to pass the task **myname** result pass to be the task **reverse** in the signature as an argument.

Here is my code. I want to pass the task **myname** result pass to be the task **reverse** in the signature as an argument.

```
from app import app
from app import app
from time import sleep
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
import os
from celery import signature, chain, group, chord
from celery.result import allow_join_result


MyQUEUE = os.getenv("SCANS_QUEUE")
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@app.task(queue=MyQUEUE, ignore_result=True)
def reverse(text):
    logger.info('reverse order '.format(text))
    return {"reversename": str(text[::-1])}

@app.task(queue=MyQUEUE, ignore_result=True)
def add(a,b):
    logger.info('Addition --> a : {0} & b : {1} '.format(a,b))
    return {"addition": str(a+b)}

@app.task(queue=MyQUEUE, ignore_result=True)
def myname(a):
    logger.info('Name --> a : {0}'.format(a))
    return {"name": str(a)}


@app.task(queue=MyQUEUE, ignore_result=True)
def run_pipeline(a,b,n):
    resultchain = chain([
        group([
            signature(
                add,
                args=(a,b),
                queue=MyQUEUE
            ),
            signature(
                myname,
                args=(n),
                queue=MyQUEUE
            )
        ]),
        signature
        (
            reverse,
            args=(-------),
            queue=MyQUEUE
        )
    ]).apply_async()

    with allow_join_result():
        results = resultchain.join()
    return results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and most important, if you are gonna use `chain`, `group`, `starmap` or another kind of task workflow, tasks which results will be used on the future need to be set with `ignore_result=False` or omit the argument (default value is False). Needed to store the value, at least on `myname` and `add`

```py
@app.task(queue=MyQUEUE)
def add(a,b):
    logger.info('Addition --> a : {0} & b : {1} '.format(a,b))
    return {"addition": str(a+b)}

@app.task(queue=MyQUEUE)
def myname(a):
    logger.info('Name --> a : {0}'.format(a))
    return {"name": str(a)}
```

Now, for `reverse` to obtain the results in the `group` of `add` and `myname`, you need to adjust `reverse` to handle the group result (a list of the results).

For a `chain` the results of a task will be used as the first argument of the next task, in this case the group results will be injected in the first value of the reverse task as `[{'addition': ...}, {'name': ...}]`, with that you can access the correct value.

```
@app.task(queue=MyQUEUE)
def reverse(group_data):
    # group_data value: [{'addition': '3'}, {'name': 'VALUE'}]
    text = group_data[1]['name']
    logger.info('reverse order '.format(text))
    return {"reversename": str(text[::-1])}
```

Finally if you only want to reverse the result of `myname`, you have to chain only `myname` and `reverse`.

```py
resultchain = chain([
    signature(myname, args=(n,)),
    signature(reverse)
]).apply_async()
```

Comment: thank you Patricio, How do i run add function in group?

Comment: You can use a chain inside the group `group([chain(...), signature(add, ...)])`.